# Login to SQL Server 2012 Express

Tags: sql-server, authentication

My current situation is kind of weird. I can successfully login to the Server using Windows Authentication (SQL Server Management Studio). In there I can open the "Security -> Logins" branch and I do see `sa` user. Then I can right click on the `sa` user and in the menu, select "Properties". Next in the "Login Properties - sa" window I can enter a new password for the user "sa" and hit "OK".

But when I disconnect, and then try to reconnect inside Management Studio, using SQL Server Authentication, I am getting the error message:

> Login failed for user sa

I didn't enable "Mixed Mode" on the install, only afterwards.

Moreover, I tried to login to the box from Linux using: "busybox telnet 192.168.1.4 1433", where "192.168.1.4" is an IP address of the machine. And of course I opened the port 1433 on both Windows Firewall and CoMoDo FW I have installed. I'm running Windows 8.1 here.

Does anybody have an idea of what is going on? Or at the very least how to fix the SQL Server behavior?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you check the SQL Server logs?  Should show the error state.

Comment: @JimHewitt, how do I do that? I am not a DBA, programmer.

Comment: .Nevermind, found it. It says "Server configured for Windows Authentication only.". I guess I will need to redo this...